# Control of video texture in A-Frame

Tags: html5-video, textures, aframe

In A-Frame, how can I control a video (ie pause, play) which is being used as a texture on a cube utilizing the multisrc component (https://github.com/elbobo/aframe-multisrc-component) with the cursor?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, see ngokevin's answer below for playback controls. I will just add an apology as there was a bug that was stopping video playback on the multisrc component. Its fixed now, if you go to the github page https://github.com/elbobo/aframe-multisrc-component and use the new script (0.3)  then it should work. Sorry about that. I hope it works out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<video id="src0">`

`<a-entity id="cube" multisrc="src0: #src0" handler>`

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('handler', {
  init: function () {
    this.el.addEventListener('click', () => {
      document.getElementById('src0').pause()
    });
  },
});
```